What is Palifit mean in the Rabeinu Gershom on Baba Basrah 2a?
BH
What does it mean Palifit it this Rabeinu Gershom in Daf B amud Alef in Bava Basra?


What tractate is this from?

It would be helpful if you showed what word or phrase he was commenting on (i.e. the entire דיבור המתחיל).

Bava Basra first daf

https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/palafitte seems like a pile of wood sticks fastened together or piled ontop based off this word

@sam Maybe it's "pulpit"?

palafitte are vertical wooden pilings set in the ground.

Welcome to MiYodeya and thanks for this first answer. Great to have you learn with us!

See here in the book "Der Orient" in which it claims in the name of שד"ל (I am assuming this is Rabbi Shmuel David Luzzatto) that this is an Italian word.
Here is the Cambridge Dictionary translation

stilts  [noun plural] tall poles fixed under a house etc to support it eg if it is built on a steep hillside

